# Blog posts permalinks correct but recent post widgets goes to my website and not staying on my blog site

Tags: posts

I am a novice, but I have my website, online store and blog looking the way I want them.  I had to change my blog theme because the widgets were in the wrong place so I chose another theme (raindrops). The only problem is that my blog widgets such as categories, recent posts, etc., when clicked on go to my website instead of my blog site.

The blog and store are subdomains under digitaldesignzonline.com  and all have separate folders and wordpress installs.  My website digitaldesignzonline.com (so far) is working great, and my store: digitaldesignzonline.com/store seems to be also.

The only problem is my blog: digitaldesignzonline.com/blog.  When I click on the recent posts widget in the sidebar, the address show the correct post link and name, but actually goes to my website (digitaldesignzonline.com)

My blog pages direct back to the website, but that doesn't bother me.  I think it is where the problem may be? It is a child theme.

I have tried different themes, deleted  a ton of plugins that were not activated, checked the permalinks settings, and tried everything I can think of.
I have googled for 12 hours and can't find the problem.  Please help me before I have a stroke trying to figure this out!
PS I am a novice at php, etc., but can follow instructions if clear and precise.

You will be my hero if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "WordPress address (URL)" is set correctly under Settings > General.